# PHP arrays replacement

Tags: php, arrays, replace

```
$data = Array ( ['key1'] => 1 , ['key2'] => 20 , ['key3'] => 11)
$key1 = Array (1 => "a" , 2 => "b")
$key2 = Array (1 => "a" , .... 20 => "y") 
$key3 = Array (1 => "a" , .... 11 => "n")
```

what is the easiest way to replace all values in $data array to return:

```
$data['key1'] = $key1[$data['key1']]
```

instead of doing that one by one i.e:

```
$data['key1'] = $key1[$data['key1']]
$data['key2'] = $key2[$data['key2']]...
```

Comment: Your question is not clear..:(

Comment: I quoted your array keys - assuming this isn't pseudocode, you ought to crank up error reporting, where you'd be seeing piles and piles of E_NOTICE about undefined constants interpreted as strings (unless you actually defined all those constants, which seems unlikely)

Comment: why not use an $data['key1']['value1'] .... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
foreach($data as $k => &$v)
{
    if($$k)
    {
        $t = $$k;
        if($t[$v]) $v = $t[$v];
    }
}

print_r($data);
```

but I'd suggest asking yourself some bigger questions about the intent here

Comment: mmm now it's better, so $t = $$k; this made all the difference but why!!

Comment: i don't know, i've never really used variable variables much. i guess you just can't index on them directly - i tried using parens `($$k)[$v]` without any luck too

Comment: any way your answer deserve to be chosen as the right answer because it's a little bit simpler than @andy's

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite hard to understand, but I think what you're trying to do is use `$data` to pull data from the other arrays. If that's the case, this should work:

```
$data = array('key1' => 1, 'key2' => 2, 'key3' => 0);
$key1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$key2 = array(6,7,8,9,10);
$key3 = array(11,12,13,14);

foreach(array_keys($data) as $key) {
  if(isset($$key)) {
    $target = $$key;
    $value = $target[$data[$key]];

    $data[$key] = $value;
  }
}

var_dump($data); #=> [key1 => 2, key2 => 8, key3 => 11]
```

Comment: and since your answer is the only right one could you please explain why jon_darkstar's answer and quinqui's are wrong even they seems just right but they didn't work

Comment: If you take a look at the last edit I made, this one wouldn't of worked either because PHP has a weird bug when referencing double variable arrays. `$a = array(0,1,2); $b = 'a'; echo $$b[0]` wouldn't work but `$a = array(0,1,2); $b = 'a'; $c = $$b; echo $c[0]` would for some bizarre reason

Answer (score 1):

i'd prefer this solution

```
array_walk(
    $data,
    function(&$a, $b) {
        $a = $$a[$b];
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using PHP's variables variables, something like this:

```
foreach ($data as $mkey => $mval)
{
 $data[$mkey] = $$mkey[$data[$mkey]];
}
```

Comment: Answering to user2903728's comment in @andy's post, I must say my code fails because I'm replacing a value from the same array I'm going through. The idea was to show you the use of variables variables :s

Comment: No that's not the answer because It works when replacing the value from the main array but it doesn't work without assigning the variables variables to another variable, for example you can use:
$t = $$k;$v = $t[$v];
but $v = $$k[$v] won't work

Comment: Uh, I didn't know that :o Well, thanks @andy's code works well ^^U